# Fetching records from 3 different tables with a condition in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am having an issues with fetching a particular kind of record from the database.

I have three different tables

1. Friends
2. Followers
3. PictureGalleries

Here is a sample of what the table looks like

```
Friends:

|id | senderId | receiverId | accepted |   
|---|----------| -----------| ---------|   
| 1 | 1        | 12         | 1        |     
| 2 | 12       | 2          | 1        |  
| 2 | 12       | 2          | 1        |


Followers:

| id | userId | UserIsFollowing |  
| -- | ------ | --------------- |  
| 1  | 12     | 63              |  
| 2  | 22     | 12              |

PictureGalleries:

| id | UserId |   
| -- | ------ |  
| 1  | 13     |  
| 2  | 12     |  
| 3  | 1      |  
| 4  | 10     |  
| 5  | 2      |  
| 6  | 63     |
```

So now here is the Issue!

I want to select all from the Picture Galleries
Where the userid has a friendship relationship with userId 12 where accepted is 1
And
Where the userID 12 is following a particular user

So Basically the result I want to see is the picture gallery of the following users ID: 1,2, and 63 which will look like this:

```
| id | UserID |
| -- | ------ |
| 3  | 1      |
| 5  | 2      |
| 6  | 6      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use union and sub-query to get desired result

```
   select p.id,p.UserId from
   ( select UserIsFollowing as id from 
   Followers fl where userId =12 
   union select senderId from friends f 
   where f.receiverId =12 AND accepted=1 
   union select receiverId from friends f 
    where f.senderId =12 AND accepted=1 
   ) as t join PictureGalleries p on t.id=p.UserId
```

Comment: I made few changes to your answer and it worked. Here it is.

    select p.id,p.UserId  from 

  (  select UserIsFollowing as id  
     from Followers fl where userId =12
    union 
    select senderId  from friends f where f.receiverId =12 AND                               accepted=1
    union
    select receiverId from friends f where f.senderId  =12 AND accepted=1
  ) as t join PictureGalleries p on t.id=p.UserId

Comment: @kelrob if it helps then accept my answer i am going to update yours few change answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this query shows what you want:

```
select * from PictureGalleries
    join Followers on Followers.userId = PictureGalleries.UserId
    where exists (select 1 from Friends where (Friends.senderId = PictureGalleries.UserId or Friends.receiverId  = PictureGalleries.UserId) and accepted = 1)
    and Followers.UserIsFollowing  = :user_id
```

But I think your model can be improved

EDIT:

Maybe you said it wrong first when you've said:

"Where the userid has a friendship relationship with userId 12 where accepted is 1
**AND** Where the userID 12 is following a particular user"

I think you mean OR, so the SQL should be something like:

```
select * from PictureGalleries
where exists (select 1 from Friends where (Friends.senderId = PictureGalleries.UserId or Friends.receiverId  = PictureGalleries.UserId) and accepted = 1)
OR exists (select 1 from Followers where Followers.userId = PictureGalleries.UserId and Followers.UserIsFollowing  = :user_id
```

Comment: I keep getting empty results when I tried running the sql query

Comment: Is the followers table complete? Or has just this 2 rows?